# How do I set up an RSS feed for my hard-coded php & mysql site?

Tags: php, mysql, rss

I have absolutely no idea how to start one. Every tutorial I find assumes I have a cms or blog of some sort. Mine's not exactly. I upload everything and coded all my css, html, mysql, php, and such. So how do I create an RSS feed?

I'm guessing I need to use a php include right?

Also I want my RSS feed to be automated if possible. Like all it'll need to know is the title of my page, and then the RSS will send it out to all my subscribers with the link of the page as the only description.

Please post any info you have though, as beggars can't be choosers.

Thanks!

Comment: RSS for what exactly? As I understand you don't have dynamically created content.

Comment: No I do not. I just want to submit my pages to RSS. What does dynamically created content have to do with anything?

Comment: `RSS (most commonly expanded as Really Simple Syndication) is a family of web feed formats used to publish frequently updated works—such as blog entries, news headlines, audio, and video—in a standardized format.` Nothing. Are you looking for sitemap maybe do you update your site frequently (no matter how)?

Answer (score 1):

Generate a list of filenames, order them by timestamp, read them, extract title and content snippets, and finally print out an RSS document. Example:

```
// list + sort
$files = glob("pages/*.html");
$files = array_combine($files, array_map("filemtime", $files));
arsort($files);

// loop + read
foreach ($files as $fn=>$mtime) {

    $html = file_get_contents($fn);
    preg_match('#<title>([^<]+)', $html, $title) and $title=$title[1];

    $rss[] = array(
        "link" => $fn,
        "pubDate" => $mtime,
        "title" => $title,
        "description" => substr(strip_tags($html), 0, 100),
    );
}

// write RSS
foreach ($rss ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Manually create a file containing the RSS XML referencing the pages from your site that you want in your feed. As you add new pages to your site, update that RSS file.  The file should be stored along with other files comprising your site.

See the example on Wikipedia for the format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS#Example

Answer (score 0):

Read up on RSS (http://www.w3schools.com/rss/default.asp). you don't have to send anything out; just update the RSS feed, and if they are subscribed the change will propagate through to the end-user. This can either be a semi-automated process that pulls in information as you update your page (why tutorials presuppose a blog or cms), or you can update the feed manually.